# Multi-Tenancy Data Architecture - Shared Schema - Security

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption, multi-tenant, amazon-rds

A new project we are starting requires MultiTenancy. At storage level this can be done at several ways. (separate Database / separate schemas / Shared schema )

To keep the operational costs down we believe that "Shared Schema - Shared Tables" is the best way to continue. So all the tenants will share the same table on the same database/schema schema.

However a constraint is to provide good tenant isolation and security. For this we can use encryption. If we are able to provide each tenant with a own keypair, then we provide good security and good isolation. Each tenant can only read his own data and we don't have to add a discriminator field at each table as well.

How can we implement this technically? If you query your table we will get a lot of data we are not able to decrypt ( data from other tenants ). Also in Joins etc it will have higher load due to the other records being in database.

I've already read a couple of articles on MSDN and watched some presentations, but they keep it very high level and abstract. Any thoughts on this ? 
Is something like described above possible? I thought you could do something on Amazon RDS ? Is it possible to provide some example  - eg on github?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shared, and with some reading between the lines, I am wary of this approach. By itself, shared schema is a very reasonable design for multi-tenancy; where I see problems is with the suggested use of encryption.

While PostgreSQL does support encryption, it's done via functions in the pgcrypto module. RDS, as a managed service for PostgreSQL, adds the ability to easily provision encrypted volumes as well, but to a database user/developer, it's going to look pretty much the same.

The docs suggest using pgcrypto if you only need to encrypt small subsets of your data that you don't need to filter or join on  - but it's not clear how much of the data you are looking to encrypt. If only a handful of columns and don't need to filter on them, this may work. Otherwise, reconsider - extensive use of the pgcrypto functions will render almost all standard database operations impossibly inefficient. A where clause will require decrypting the column, in turn requiring scanning/decrypting the full table; there would be zero use of indexes. Your performance will slow to a crawl very quickly.

A major consideration you haven't provided is how you are providing access - for example, a web application, where you completely mediate access with a single, trusted account? Or allowing the customers to connect directly to the database? In the former case, your code would be managing all access anyway, and would always need access to all the keys; why incur the overhead? In the latter case, you'd probably render the database unusable to the customer, because all of the standard query tools would be difficult to use.

More broadly, in my experience, a schema-per-tenant approach can offer a good balance between isolation, efficiency, and development overhead. And with judicious use of roles in PostgreSQL, you can enforce reasonable access controls for direct access (you can do the same with rows, though in my view that would require more overhead to administer correctly).

Take a look at some of the commonly used application frameworks to learn more: Rails offers the Apartment gem (https://github.com/influitive/apartment); Django has the django-tenants library (http://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); Hibernate has a pluggable tenant framework (e.g., https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)

Hope this helps.